# C# Linq Comparing List Values using multiple fields and return item which doesn't satisfy the condition

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I have a List like this called **result**

```
{ Id = "8131367", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131368", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 1500.00 }
{ Id = "8131369", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131370", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131371", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131372", GId = 27720, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131373", GId = 27721, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131374", GId = 27721, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131375", GId = 27721, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131376", GId = 27721, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 }
{ Id = "8131377", GId = 27721, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 1500.00 }
```

I need to filter the list based on GId,Share, Type, OPC, IPC having same values and Price having Different value. So from the list the second and the last one having a Price Different So I need to get that list or Id Property from the List Item which have price different and rest of the values same.

By Using Two Foreach loops I was able to get what i needed but unfortunately I was asked to convert it into a LINQ query. this is what I tried

```
var items = result.Select(r => result.Where(rr => (r.GId == rr.GId) 
                                                   && (r.Share == rr.Share) 
                                                   && (r.Type == rr.Type) 
                                                   && (r.IPC == rr.IPC) 
                                                   && (r.OPC == rr.OPC) 
                                                   && (r.Price != rr.Price))).ToList();
```

But from the query above I am not getting what I wanted, I believe I am near to what I needed but I lack the expertise with LINQ.

Comment: Could you post your previous code with the loops ?

Comment: @Arcord I dont have it right now. its Nested foreach loop like 
foreach(var item1 in result ) {
 foreach(var item2 in result) {
 if(item1.GId == item2.GId && ... item1.Price != item2.Prices)
 { // sets item1.Id into a list }
 }
}

Comment: If you have code that you want converted into a link query, then *that's* probably the code you should show. Either that or describe how the code you've posted isn't providing the expected results.

Comment: `GroupBy` is typically a good way to get items that are related by some common properties.

Comment: The thing is that it isn't altogether clear what you want to accomplish. Are you comparing against a set of input values? Or are you wanting to say "all the rows that have the same X, Y and Z, only return the one that has a different price from the others in the same group".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If You see the result list Other than Price GId is Unique for a set of data. So the Price difference is checked against each set grouped by GId. List with GID 27720 and 27721 can be considered two different Set of Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**Group by**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) to group all properties except `Id`, like the following code :

```
var items = result.GroupBy(x => new { x.GId, x.Share, x.Type, x.OPC, x.IPC, x.Price })
    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
    .ToList();
```

**Demo**

```
foreach(Test item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Id:{item.Id}, GID:{item.GId}, Price:{item.Price}");
}
```

**Result**

```
Id:8131368, GID:27720, Price:1500
Id:8131377, GID:27721, Price:1500
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: In this case he would like to have only the one whose price differs. You could remove the groups with more than 1 element and it will be OK :-)

Comment: @Arcord, i have already update the answer, i have a doubt if the OP want also one element of duplicated rows.but after i'm rereading the question, i  left all elements for groupby and i'm using `where count == 1` that gives only not duplicated rows. thank you.+1

Comment: @Sajid this also will return groups which have only one  element for `{ x.GId, x.Share, x.Type, x.OPC, x.IPC}`

Comment: @GuruStron, if i understood correctly, by this query, if i delete price from ``groupby``, ``Where(x => x.Count() == 1)`` will gives 0, because we have 6 + 6 duplicated rows without price and Id.

Comment: @Sajid add `{ Id = "8131367", GId = 27722, Share = 1.0000, Type = "1029", OPC = "997", IPC = "997", Price = 500.00 } ` (unique `GId `) to OP's example.

Comment: @GuruStron the OP said : *I need to filter the list based on GId,Share, Type, OPC, IPC having same values and Price having Different value*, i think for the row mentioned in your comment, does not have the same values, automatically it's a new rows without checking the price.

Comment: @Sajid i would assume OP either does not have such edge case or have not thought of it, but from the quote - for list of one all prices are the same)

Answer (score 1):

This will work but is not optimized at all:

```
var result2 = result
    .GroupBy(i => new {i.GId, i.Share, i.Type, i.OPC, i.IPC})
    .Select(i1 => i1.LastOrDefault(i2 => i1.Count(i3 => i3.Price == i2.Price) == 1))
    .ToList();
```

It will return the row with id "8131368" and "8131377"

**Edit**
This code works but ask for a nested loop that can be avoided. Check the Sajid's answer with my comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to get that list or Id Property from the List Item which have price different and rest of the values same

You can group by value tuple containing properties that should be equal and then select groups with more then one element:

```
var itemIds = result
    .GroupBy(r => (r.GId, r.Share, r.Type, r.IPC, r.OPC))
    .Where(g => g.Select(r => r.Price).Distinct().Count() > 1) // or Count() == 2, then next clause can be simplified
    .Select(g => 
    {
        var byPrice = g.GroupBy(r => r.Price).ToList();
        
        if(byPrice.Count > 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not determine base price - more than 2 groups");
        }
        
        if (byPrice.All(gg => gg.Count() == 1))
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not determine base price - multiple groups with single element");
        }
        
        return byPrice.First(gg => gg.Count() == 1).Select(r => r.Id).First();
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i think this query, returns two elements with different GID and same price.

Comment: you have another issue `g` has conflict with last line :)

Comment: @Sajid actually it works o my machine, but fixed for clarity